# Doctrine - using the same table for multiple (many-to-many) relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Say I have three entities: Page, Product and Media.

Well, I would like to have this realations:

```
Page <-(many-to-many)-> Media

Product <-(many-to-many)-> Media
```

Using the common approach for solving this, it would result two tables that look very similar.

My question is: Can I use a single table for both relations using Doctrine?

What I only need is a way of suggesting a new column that would indicate if the counterpart of media on a particular row is Product or Page.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is No. Relations table N:N must have unique table name. 
But... You can aways create a structure of that kind:

```
Page <--1:N--> MyGreatJoinTable <--N:1--> Media
Product <--1:N--> MyGreatJoinTable <--N:1--> Media
```

You don't need to describe the reference because it refers to a different table, but if you want you can do it.

Of course MyGreatJoinTable will have at least three columns:

```
- PageId
- ProductId
- MediaId
```

Comment: Yes, this could be an approach. Thank you! +1